# devtools::check_man() gives error but devtools::check() does not

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm developing a package (https://github.com/dpmcsuss/iGraphMatch/).

I just started using `devtools::check()` etc to check for issues. Currently, I'm getting no errors, warnings, or notes (YAY).

Unfortunately, sometimes I want to use `devtools::check_man()` to just check the documentation for issues since that should be much faster. When I run this I get the following output.

```
> devtools::check_man()
Updating iGraphMatch documentation
Loading iGraphMatch
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Checking documentation...
Error: cannot source package code:
cannot add bindings to a locked environment
```

I've tried detaching the package, unloading the namespace, making sure files were not locked, uninstalling the package, .... Nothing seems to make a difference.

If I make a new package everything works fine. I realize this is far from a minimum working example but I'm pretty unsure about where to start looking. Any suggestions would be appreciated. (One thing that I haven't explored yet is whether the order things are documented matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in R.  If you delete all your code except for the `setClass` in `matrix_list.R`, you still get the error.  If you delete the `matrix_list.R` file and nothing else, you don't.

This happens if you use `tools::checkDocStyle(dir = "iGraphMatch")`, you don't need `devtools` involved at all.

I'd conclude that there's some incompatibility between the tools::checkDocStyle function and S4 `methods::setClass`.  I have no idea if there's a workaround.

Edited to add:  There's a fairly simple workaround for this bug.  Instead
of using the code

```
matrix_list <- setClass("matrix_list", contains = "list")
```

in the `matrix_list.R` file, use this nearly equivalent code:

```
setClass("matrix_list", contains = "list")

matrix_list <- function(...)
  new("matrix_list", ...)
```

This avoids triggering the bug in `tools::checkDocStyle`.  It's not quite identical, because the original adds some extra attributes on the generator function, but it should probably be close enough.